# Inheritance in IronPython and circular references

Tags: python, ironpython

I have a question about circular references in IronPython. Let's say that I have class hierarchy. In one file I have parent class:

```
from Child import Child

class Parent(object):
    def getChild(self):
        return Child()
```

In another file I have child class:

```
from Parent import Parent

class Child(Parent):
    def doSomething(self):
        return 0
```

I have kind of circular references here. So, when I try to execute code like this:

```
from Parent import *

parent = Parent()
child = parent.getChild()
```

I've got an error:
[image]
Can I avoid this circular reference in some kind of way?

Comment: Do you actually need these classes to be in separate files?

Comment: Yes, I can't modify files structure. Actually my real example is a little bit more complicated and I reproduced this error on a very simple example with two classes in separate files. I'm searching for any solution for this kind of a problem but I've got no results yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you have a circular import problem.

The normal way of solving this is to simply have the two classes in the same file. Python does not enforce any kind of link between file and class, so you can have as many classes as you like in a single file and they can be called whatever you like. (In fact, giving the file the exact same name as the class it contains is *un*-Pythonic; apart from anything else, files should have lower_case_with_underscore names, whereas classes are CamelCase.)

However, if for some reason you can't do that, you can break the circular import by doing it inside the method:

```
class Parent(object):
    def getChild(self):
        from child import Child
        return Child()
```